# Bootgrid's search is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-bootgrid

I'm trying to run the search of Bootgrid but when I enter data into the search field stays loading. The webmethod from server side return a list of DTO's that are automatically serialized , since the data is displayed correctly. I 've looked everywhere , documentation , examples and I cannot get to see which might be the problem, what should I do to make the search work? Thank you

[This is the asp.net code](https://jsfiddle.net/a796kwnq/34/)

This is the DTO which i return a list of.

```
Namespace Data.DTO
Public Class CarSearchDTO
    Private _id As Integer
    Private _brand As String
    Private _model As String

    Public Property id As Integer
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property brand As String
        Get
            Return _brand
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _brand = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property model As String
        Get
            Return _model
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _model = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

End Namespace

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i have a commands column which i dont put it as not searchable, so it give an error when the search look for in that column. Just add data-searchable="false" in that column and it work fine.